# (short form to) Ignore multiple filename patterns using “find”?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, regex, find

It seems I can ignore a certain filename pattern (`*.dll`) on find search by doing

```
find ! -name '*.dll'
```

And ignore multiple patterns by doing

```
$ find . ! -name '*.h' ! -name '*.cpp' ! -name '*.dll'
```

Is there a short form of this?

I tried (unsuccessfully) the following

```
$ find . ! -name '*.h *.cpp *.dll'
```

Comment: Try `find . ! -name '*.h','*.cpp','*.dll'` and lemme know if it works. I don't ever use the find command so I'm not 100% sure if that will work or not.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: why dont you create a alias of this command `find . ! -name '*.h' ! -name '*.cpp' ! -name '*.dll` alias mycommand="find . ! -name '*.h' ! -name '*.cpp' ! -name '*.dll",if you want to persist between shell session add this to your .bashrc, so next time you want to run this just type mycommand so sleek

Answer (score 3):

If your version of `find` has a `-regex` primary, you can use that. Unfortunately, it's nonstandard, and you need extended regex syntax which is even less standard. With [GNU `find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find), you use `-regextype` to set the regular expression syntax (and it goes *after* the directory to search), so it'd be something like this:

```
find . -regextype egrep '!' -regex '.*[.](h|cpp|dll)'
```

With [BSD (/macOS) `find`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/find/), you'd use the `-E` option *before* the directory to search, so it looks like this:

```
find -E . '!' -regex '.*[.](h|cpp|dll)'
```

Note that this is a regular expression, not a glob (wildcard) pattern, so you have to use `.*` to match any string, and escape or bracket the `.` so it won't be treated as "match any single character". Also, the regex pattern is matched against the entire path, not just the filename (doesn't matter here, but it would would other patterns).